# Theming the reset password mail sent to to user

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I want to theme the mail which is used to send a link to user when he/she forgot the password.I want to know what i need to name that template file so that drupal will take my email template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for my question. The file name should be

> mimemail-message--password_reset.tpl.php

Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but the above answer is only true if you have the MIMEmail module installed. https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail